# How to get rid of "demo" from geowebcache layer link

Tags: geowebcache

I wan to use standalone geowebcache. I know how to serve cached layers but one thing really annoys me and it is the "demo" in the link e.g.

```
http://myserver.com/geowebcache/demo/layer
```

I would like to have the link in form without the "demo" or to be able to change it to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake, the demo is in the link only if you view the service within the geowebcache.